# How to replace characters in npm script

Tags: node.js

i have an npm package that have scripts, now i want to use package version to bind gcp app engine service version, but it does not allow '.' character in version, only '-'.

So i want to replace '.' with '-' when i execute the script, this is my attempt:

```
{
  "name": "my-package-blablabla",
  ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "gcp:deploy": "gcloud app deploy --no-promote --version=${npm_package_version//./-}"
  }
}
```

but in this way i get the following error:

```
sh: 1: Bad substitution
```

executing it directly from bash it works:

```
$ version="1.2.3"
$ echo ${version//./-}
1-2-3
```

how i can do it in npm script?

p.s. (will be nice if there is solution that is windows compatible)

Answer (score -1):

one solution can be

```
"gcp:deploy": "gcloud app deploy --no-promote --version=$(echo $npm_package_version | tr '.' '-')",
```

but i dont really like it and i don't think that is windows compatible